# Amazon S3 Integration

Tags: java, php, actionscript-3, open-source, amazon-s3

I am trying to integrate S3 with one of my content management systems. The idea is that I want to have document control features.

The system is quite unique in that it handles thousands of sites, then each site can have any number of contributors or authors who have permission to upload documents and files to the document control module of the site.

I haven't coded the document control module yet, but I would like to get started right away. 
I know there are good developer tools for S3 already, however I would really like to make this even easier and even use third party open source products if they are licensable under resale. 
Does anyone know of any kind of Java apps for example which makes uploading to S3 easy, or should I just concentrate on developing something which is targetted for my specific case usages.

I do a lot of interface design, but for this, I am really not sure how I should handle it, so I would be grateful also if people could provide examples of websites which have good support for document control and makes it look easy. I don't want something complicated which crazily complex workflow rules, I just want to create something so that site owners can publish documents, images etc. Manage the versions of them and also have a centralised bucket for adding site themes are images.

Comment: If I need to clarify more, please let me know. I can see that the question might be a little ambiguous and its really several questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good PHP class to get you started with uploading files and managing buckets - http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

Answer (score 1):

For java jets3t is the best I hav found: https://jets3t.dev.java.net/

I've used their packaged software and the libs in my own apps and both work very well.